# How to Increase the Vertical Spacing Between the Last Two Lines of This Macro Aligned Output

Tags: macros, minipage, alignment, vertical-spacing, justification

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\LARGE
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{5.75in}\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}%
\textbf{How to increase the vertical spacing between the second-to-last and the last line? How to increase the vertical spacing between the second-to-last and the last line? How to increase the vertical spacing between the second-to-last and the last line?}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

with the output

[image]

Sometimes, although it may not be so apparent here---the vertical space between the penultimate line and the last line is noticeably less than the vertical space between other pairs of consecutive lines.

QUESTION: How may the macro alignment command `\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}%` be modified (or perhaps, another approach would be more appropriate) in order to increase the vertical space between the last two lines *only*---while maintaining the current vertical spacing between the other lines in the aligned output of this minipage environment?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you quite sure that the last line is closer to the line above it than the distance between other pairs of lines?  Measuring it (on my screen), the distances are the same.  I think it's an illusion, since the penultimate line has no descenders in the center, while the last line starts and ends with tall characters,  if you really want to "force" it, you can put a `\strut` at the end, and another one somewhere it will fall on the previous line, say after `last\strut\ `.  (Don't forget that inter-word space.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Not necessarily in the MWE; but often enough in actual documents. So, I ask here---how to increase the space between the said lines so that I can incorporate it in actual documents when such occurs.

Comment: the baselineskip in all lines of a paragraph is always the same, so what you describe can not happen, or at least not for the reasons you give. Obviously if some lines  have an over-large item and force `\lineskip` space, the remaining lines have smaller spacing, but nothing special for the last line

Comment: you can increase the space before the last line by ending  `....line?\rule{0pt}{2cm}`

Comment: you accepted answer, so your real doc has misplaced size commands?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I do not understand what you are asking.

Comment: Although  I added a `\rule` suggestion at the end, the main point of my answer was that the problem as described in the question can not happen. I was just interested to know what the actual issue was (as the supplied example is not an example of the problem)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes; I was not able to reproduce the phenomenon that occurs every so often in my actual documents---so I asked how to increase the vertical space between the last two lines that I may incorporate it whenever I encounter such for real. Your answer seemed to provide exactly what I was looking for---that is why I upvoted and accepted it.

Comment: If you are getting uneven line spacing as in my first example, the correct solution though would always be to fix the cause, not hack in a rule at the end.

Comment: If you always end the text block with `\par`, the baselines throughout the paragraph should be uniform, as long as the font size in the paragraph is uniform.  If you *do* want a larger or smaller word in the paragraph, bury it in a group; font size commands (`\small`, `\Large`, etc.) are local.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I did not know that. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\baselineskip` in all lines of a paragraph is always the same, so what you describe can not happen, or at least not for the reasons you give.

If some items are larger than will fit on `\baselineskp` even line spacing is lost, and `\lineskip` rather than `\baselineskip` is used, however this could happen on any line, not just the last. A common reason for seeing this problem is a mis-placed size command, for example if I move `\LARGE` in your example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{5.75in}\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}%
  \textbf{\LARGE How to increase the vertical spacing between the
    second-to-last and the last line? How to increase the vertical
    spacing between the second-to-last and the last line? How to
    increase the vertical spacing between the second-to-last and the
    last line?}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

However to answer the question in the title and to add space before the last line you can use a final rule.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
\LARGE 
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{5.75in}\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}%
  \textbf{How to increase the vertical spacing between the
    second-to-last and the last line? How to increase the vertical
    spacing between the second-to-last and the last line? How to
    increase the vertical spacing between the second-to-last and the
    last line?}\rule{0pt}{3cm}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: To guarantee uniform baselines, why not just end the paragraph with an explicit `\par`?

Comment: @barbarabeeton because it can't possibly be needed, `\end{minipage}` ends the paragraph.

Comment: Ah, okay.  Forgot.  (Don't often use minipages, just change format in a local group, and terminate it explicitly.)